# Building a curved beam in 3D

Tags: 3d, maya, modeling, blender

I am currently building a Torii gate from [this concept image](https://stock.adobe.com/nl/images/torii-japanese-gate-torii-forest-background-concept-art-digital-illustration-anime-generative-ai/551275776), but am having issues building the top cross beam. I have used the bend deform, but I feel that I am not efficiently solving this problem. Could anyone give me a push in the right direction to tackle this problem?

Comment: This is not the best place to ask. Graphic designers do not in general use 3d applications. Graphic design is not about graphics but graphical communication. As such there's not communication problem here nor is there a typically used by graphic designer software present. (aside for that you don't tell what software your using, not what would be more efficient than what your doing now. After all art is dealing with tedium to one extent).  Anyway you can ask, just don't expect a terribly speedy answer to your question. Just yesterday a 3ds max question was answered only 5 years after asking.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Do you know there is a Blender Stack Exchange?  You should really post it there.  If you want you can flag your own question and ask the mods to migrate it there for you.  However you may have to edit it a bit.  You say you have "issues" but not what they are.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the job to 2 parts:

1. Create a clean machined-like 3D body by using CAD drawing techniques. It's easy at least if no exact replica is needed and it's only a lookalike version with no demands of strength nor actual crafting methods.
2. Create the complex surface colors and fine 3D details by inserting a rich enough texture. Creating it really needs 3D material design knowledge, right tools and a huge amount of practicing. It's a profession by itself and I'm afraid most of us in GDSE cannot do it properly. I'm not an exception, so to get some guidance for step 2 you maybe must ask elsewhere.

I guess you need some ideas also for step 1. It's well possible also to get it here, because many of us make often simple 3D models to get easily some part to a 2D drawing.Illustrator has few elementary 3D tools for this, but they unfortunately are too limited for your problem.

Here's an elementary attempt to make your bent beam in a CAD program or actually only a clean version of it without any fine details. The used tricks are valid for nearly any 3D modelling program which earns to be said even resemble a professional tool.

The idea is to blend cross-section profiles along curved spines. The bigger end gets some coarse tooling after the blending. Only a half of a half of the beam must be made and the rest can be got by mirroring it twice.

Start by sketching some cross-section profiles (only halves) which really can be blended nicely i.e. corresponding details can be found from both of them:

[image]

The red rectangle is there only to remember the original sketching plane. I hate to be forced to remember it otherwise.

Move and rotate the profiles to their final places and orientations. Draw some blending spine curves between the corners to be sure the blending finds the routes right:

[image]

The smaller profile will be used as a mirror to get the right half, so be sure the spine curvess are perpendicular to the smaller profile. To get it you must move the spline control points or sketch with constraits (tricky, but it's exact). I only eyeballed the control points.

Blend the profiles along the drawn spine curves:

[image]

Sketch some lines to the bigger end surface. By dividing the surface you can easily push some parts shorter and rotate the faces.

[image]

This is the end of the half-beam after removing some material:

[image]

Here's the result after mirroring the part twice:

[image]

The end faces should be tilted. Here they are rotated few degrees by selecting them all in one end and by applying rotate just once, The mirrored half follows:

[image]

Rough crafting can be added in this phase also without inserting a bumpy surface texture. One can insert and remove material by drawing new details and applying Booleans. Many programs also have surface editing tools. Or one can convert the solid to a dense enough polygon mesh and do some sculpting. I promised only a clean version, so I stop here.